# How to parallel process multiple async task foreach loop

Tags: c#, performance, async-await, concurrency

How can I simultaneously process multiple tasks in a forach each loop, the isconnected is set by the `await item.GetIsConnected()` call. At the moment the refresh is slow, so I would like for them to process simultaneously.

Before:

```
private async void Refresh()
{
    foreach (var item in Cars.ToList<Carnet>())
    {
        await item.GetIsConnected();
        if (item.IsConnected)
        {
            await item.GetCarDetailsAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

After:

```
private async void Refresh()
{
    List<Task> listOfTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var item in Cars.ToList<Carnet>())
    {
        listOfTasks.Add(item.GetIsConnected());
        if (item.IsConnected)
        {
            await item.GetCarDetailsAsync();
        }
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks);
}
```

Comment: Have you done any profiling to check what is actually slow? If this is some API you are querying you would likely get better performance with less effort if the query let you fetch details for multiple cars at the same time.

Comment: @JonasH Each iteration is fetching data from a deffence IP address. its not massively slow. what I mean is that. It is fetching from IP address 1 checking connection get detail then the second IP address starts after IP 1 finished ... on so on instead I would like IP 1 and 2 start processing at the same time

Comment: How is the `item.GetIsConnected()` method related with the `item.IsConnected` property?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias `item.GetIsConnected()` updates `item.IsConnected`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not awaiting the call to `GetIsConnected()` in your **AFTER** example, the loop will continue and the value may or may not be checked against what it would be once the call to `GetIsConnected()` is finished, what I think you'd want to do is add another method with a return type of `Task` and let the method call `GetIsConnected()` and `await` it inside the method then call `GetCarDetailsAsync()` if necessary:

```
//changed to return type of Task, as async void should be avoided
//unless this is an event handler method
private async Task Refresh()
//private async void Refresh() //change to this if event handler
{
    List<Task> listOfTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var item in Cars.ToList<Carnet>())
    {
        listOfTasks.Add(GetCarDetails(item));        
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

//method to await the call to GetIsConnect() 
//and then call GetCarDetailsAsync() if necessary
private async Task GetCarDetails(Carnet c)
{
    await c.GetIsConnected();
    if (c.IsConnected)
    {
        await c.GetCarDetailsAsync();
    }
}
```